# Not able to fetch the dynamic select list data from from html to php. please advice

Tags: php, html, mysql

```
<form method="POST" name="mailform" action="sendmail.php">
<fieldset>

<?php
    require_once("mysql_connect.php");
    $sql = mysql_query( " SELECT NAME FROM TABLE WHERE ID = ( SELECT ID FROM TABLE2 WHERE COLUMN = '$USERNAME') ORDER BY NAME");
    echo "<select>";
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
    echo "<option value='".$row["NAME"]."'>".$row["NAME"]."</option>";
    }mysql_free_result($sql);
    echo "</select>";
?>

<input type="text" name = "name" placeholder = "name Required" ><br \><br \>
<input type="checkbox"  name="instance[]" value="yes" checked="checked" \>instance1><br>
<input type="checkbox"  name="instance[]" value="Yes" \>instance2<br><br \>
<input type="submit" name="email" value="Send Mail">
</fieldset> <br \>
</form> <br \><br \>
```

This the part of the code. I need to build sendemail.php which should have the value from dynamic select list, and value from the check boxes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    <?php
        require_once("mysql_connect.php");
        $sql = mysql_query( " SELECT NAME FROM TABLE WHERE ID = ( SELECT ID FROM TABLE2 WHERE COLUMN = '$USERNAME') ORDER BY NAME");
        echo "<select name='selection'>";
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
        echo "<option value='".$row["NAME"]."'>".$row["NAME"]."</option>";
        }mysql_free_result($sql);


echo "</select>";
?>
```

change your php code with above.. you'll get `$_POST['selection']` from dynamic select list.

**Edit:**

You'll get `$_POST['instance']` array.

```
<?php
$selected = $_POST['selection'];
$instances = array();
foreach ($_POST['instance'] as $instance)
{
    $instances[] = $instance;
}
?>
```

Now, you'll have `$selected` as dynamic selected value and `$instances` have array of checked checkboxes.

Comment: dynamic list working. how to fetch multiple results of checkbox?

Answer (score 0):

To get the value of a selected item in a list

```
<select id="items" name="animal">                      
      <option value="0">--Select Animal--</option>
      <option value="Cat">Cat</option>
</select>

$selected_val = $_POST['items'];
```

To get the selected checkbox values

```
Red <input type="checkbox" name="color[]" id="color" value="red">
Green <input type="checkbox" name="color[]" id="color" value="green">

$colorsChecked = $_GET['color'];

foreach ($color as $colorsChecked)
{
    echo $color;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

your select box must has a name.

```
 echo "<select name='cbouser'>";
```

after post you need to use $_POST["cbouser"] or $_REQUEST["cbouser"]

Comment: how to fetch multiple results of checkbox?

Comment: $_POST["instance[]"] act as an array.So use it as an array like:       Foreach($_POST["instance[]"] as $val){ //do anything with $val}